# Dynamically Generated Dropdowns Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback, viewstate, html-select

I'm having some trouble with same Dynamically generated dropdowns and their viewstate.

Long story short, a user will upload an excel file, the file will get parsed and the dropdowns will be created for the appropriate data. This is done on when an asp button is pressed, and the controls are added to a table as follows:

```
public void generateFromSheet(OrderedDictionary columns, DataTable oppcolumns, List<string> requiredDrops)
    {
        int index = 0;
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in columns)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList()
            {
                ID = "ddlMapping" + entry.Key.ToString(),
                DataSource = columns,
                DataTextField = "Key",
                DataValueField = "Value",
                SelectedIndex = index,
                Enabled = requiredDrops.Contains(entry.Key) ? false : true
            };

            ddl.DataBind();

            DropDownList ddl2 = new DropDownList()
            {
                ID = "OpportunityMappingDdl" + index,
                DataSource = oppcolumns,
                DataTextField = "AttributeDisplayName",
                DataValueField = "TableColumnName"
            };
            ddl2.DataBind();


            HtmlTableCell td = new HtmlTableCell()
            {
                ID = "tdMapping" + index
            };
            td.Controls.Add(ddl);

            HtmlTableCell td2 = new HtmlTableCell()
            {
                ID = "tdOppMapping" + index
            };
            td2.Controls.Add(ddl2);

            HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow()
            {
                ID = "trMapping" + index
            };
            tr.Cells.Add(td);
            tr.Cells.Add(td2);

            tblFileMapping.Rows.Add(tr);
            index++;
        }
    }
```

However, on each postback after this, the drop-downs are erased. I've looked online for a solution and usually everything points to recreating the controls using the same id's as when they were created so that their state can be restored from ViewState. I've tried that as follows below by storing what I should create in ViewState:

```
public void generateFromViewState()
    {
        OrderedDictionary columns = (OrderedDictionary) ViewState["XLColumns"];

        int index = 0;
        foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in columns)
        {
            DropDownList ddl = new DropDownList()
            {
                ID = "ddlMapping" + entry.Key.ToString(),
            };

            DropDownList ddl2 = new DropDownList()
            {
                ID = "OpportunityMappingDdl" + index,
            };

            HtmlTableCell td = new HtmlTableCell()
            {
                ID = "tdMapping" + index
            };
            td.Controls.Add(ddl);

            HtmlTableCell td2 = new HtmlTableCell()
            {
                ID = "tdOppMapping" + index
            };
            td2.Controls.Add(ddl2);

            HtmlTableRow tr = new HtmlTableRow()
            {
                ID = "trMapping" + index
            };
            tr.Cells.Add(td);
            tr.Cells.Add(td2);

            tblFileMapping.Rows.Add(tr);
            index++;
        }
    }
```

I call this method in the page_load but the controls do not retain their previous data and selected values.

So a couple of things wrong here:

- On page_load the controls are recreated but their state is not restored.
- For some technical reasons, my Project Manager mentioned I should not use the Session State to store anything.
- Another PM advised me that the controls should be regenerated on page_init. BUT since I'm storing the control data in ViewState, this isn't possible because the viewstate isnt ready and my data is null.

Can anyone advise on how to succesfully restore the viewstate for these dynamically generated controls. I've tried searching everything and tried a bunch of solutions online, but nothing I have tried seems to work.

Thanks!

Comment: Any specific reasons that you are rendering HTML Table Cells and ROWS and Columns, instead of using Repeaters like Repeater, Datagrid or Gridview..

Comment: No not really, I'm modifying an existing page and the content is generated in this matter in other places, so I thought I would follow it. Those controls are done in OnInit since they have the required data beforehand, and I do not, they are retaining their state. Would using a repeater or Datagrid solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it right, but you have to recreate the controls with datasource and rebinding all controls again. Without this beeing done, you are creating controls that not match the previous. You can call your first method to do that.

Comment: Just to complement the answer, for me it is a bad call to store things in viewstate, because viewstate is transported from client side to server and server side to client, knowing that, you will be downloading and uploading all the stored data on each postback.

Comment: I need to be able to restore the user's selection on each dropdown as well, will this solution also do that, or is that something I will have to store somewhere?

Comment: This solution will do that as well. Because you will be recreating the same control that it's known by the viewstate. When the postback ends, viewstate will find that control and force the previous state.

Comment: I'll give it a shot and let you know, thanks! Edit: This should be done in PageLoad?

Comment: That worked perfectly thanks! I wasn't sure if the data-sources needed to be rebinded as all the examples I saw just mentioned that I just needed at-least the ID to be the same. Although yes I agree, using ViewState to store my datasources is really bad, I can't think of another solution.

Comment: Glad it worked. I had the same issue once, and broke my head for a few hours untill I realized that. I can't think on anything either, but if you want to give a better aproach to your viewstate storage, you can try to handle your viewstate only on server side.
I have a link that can help you whit that if you want, I belive this is the link [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188774.aspx) , but I can't garantee that it is because I'm not able to open it at work, LOL.